# Why Go can't find import package in project subdirectory?

Tags: go, import

This import worked fine when I was starting app with dev_appserver.py

I am trying to refactor to use Firestore and Go 1.13

app.go content

```
package main
import (
    "net/http"
    "workout"
)
```

Project structure:

```
app.go  
|-- workout dir  
    |-- workout.go file that contains (package workout)
```

From the root of the Working Directory I ran:
$ go run *.go

```
app.go:15:2: cannot find package "workout" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/workout (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/X/go/src/workout (from $GOPATH)
```

```
$ go run *.go workout/*.go
named files must all be in one directory; have ./ and workout/
X@MacBook-Pro Thu Oct 31 10:48:13 ~/Dropbox/go/src/workoutNew
```

```
$ go build   
app.go:15:2: cannot find package "workout" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/workout (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/X/go/src/workout (from $GOPATH)
```

Comment: The errors show that the import path is expected to be `/Users/X/go/src/workout`, but it's not there. Are you trying to use modules?

Comment: I'm not trying to use Modules. I'm trying to import a package from a subdirectory of the Working Directory.

Comment: The documentation explains how GOPATH imports work: try [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)

Comment: So if I create a new project all the files have to be in one directory and all packages I create have to be located in ~/go/src or another location on $GOPATH ?

Comment: If you're using `GOPATH`, _all_ packages must be relative to `GOAPTH`, period. Walking through How to Write Go Code provides a complete example of this. If you want to use modules, you need to first create a module and then you can import your module packages by their full module path. https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules

Comment: The project I'm posting about is @ $GOPATH/src/AppDir and the import $GOPATH/src/AppDir/workoutDir/workout.go which is generating the error.

Comment: well, following the documentation the import path for `workout` is `AppDir/workoutDir` (BTW, do _not_ use mixed case import paths, you cannot treat all systems as case-insensitive and it's likely to cause problems)

Answer (score 7):

```
import (
 "workout"
)
```

This will try to import a stdlib package called `workout`.

In order to import your `workout` package, you should name your main package (using `go mod init`), like: `github.com/me/myapp`, then import the `workout` package as `github.com/me/myapp/workout`.

Importing `workout` as a relative directory ( "./workout") also works, but that is not the recommended way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `GOPATH` and `GOROOT`:

```
/usr/local/go/src/workout (from $GOROOT)
/Users/X/go/src/workout (from $GOPATH)
```

Move your working folder under:

```
$GOPATH/my-app/
```

```
my-app
|...app.go
    workout
    |...workout.go
```

Update import:

```golang
package main
import (
    "net/http"
    "my-app/workout"
)
```

Now move to:

```
cd $GOPATH/my-app/
```

Run `app.go`:

```
go run app.go
```

Comment: I thought the convention was to put package files in a subdirectory that shared the same name as the package.

I am running app.go from the Working Directory.